# Pivot longer in R with means and CIs

Tags: r, data-cleaning

In order to make some coefficient plots, I think I need to end up with a resulting data frame with 5 columns: var, attend, mean, ci_lower, and ci_upper.

However, the way I am trying to `pivot_longer` pivots the entire data frame. How can I get it to pivot only on "attend"?

Code:

```
dtest_long <- dtest %>% 
  pivot_longer(!var, names_to = "attend", values_to = "value")
```

Data:

```
dtest <- structure(list(var = c("jbj_ext_1", "jbj_ext_2", "jbj_ext_3", 
"jbj_int_1", "jbj_int_2", "jbj_int_3", "jbj_tot_1", "jbj_tot_2", 
"jbj_tot_3"), no_attend_mean = c(11.15, 8, 7.64, 4.24, 8.26, 
7.89, 30.01, 21.08, 20.93), attend_mean = c(15.36, 10.9, 11.15, 
10.1, 4.25, 4.24, 28.98, 20.99, 19.89), no_attend_lowCI = c(9.65, 
6.5, 6.14, 2.74, 6.76, 6.39, 28.51, 19.58, 19.43), attend_lowCI = c(13.86, 
9.4, 9.65, 8.6, 2.75, 2.74, 27.48, 19.49, 18.39), no_attend_upperCI = c(12.2, 
9.05, 8.69, 5.29, 9.31, 8.94, 31.06, 22.13, 21.98), attend_upperCI = c(16.41, 
11.95, 12.2, 11.15, 5.3, 5.29, 30.03, 22.04, 20.94)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: What's `v1` ? It isn't in your example data.

Comment: Sorry, v1 should've been var. Updated.

Comment: It's not clear what the final data frame should look like. What do you mean by "pivot only on attend" ? If you are trying to keep only the mean and CI values from columns where the name starts with "attend", you can achieve that using `dplyr::select`: _e.g._ `dtest %>% select(-starts_with("no"))`. If you're trying to pivot on columns that start with "attend" then `dtest %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("attend"), names_to = "attend")`.

Comment: If I'm thinking about it correctly, there should be 2 rows for each 'var': "attend" and "not attend". The resulting columns would be var, attend, mean, ci_lower, and ci_upper. So you could see the mean and CI for each var split by attend and not attend in two rows per var. I realized I wrote 4 columns in my original Q and have updated to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your expected outcome; I think this approach would work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dtest <- structure(list(var = c("jbj_ext_1", "jbj_ext_2", "jbj_ext_3", 
                                "jbj_int_1", "jbj_int_2", "jbj_int_3", "jbj_tot_1", "jbj_tot_2", 
                                "jbj_tot_3"), no_attend_mean = c(11.15, 8, 7.64, 4.24, 8.26, 
                                                                 7.89, 30.01, 21.08, 20.93), attend_mean = c(15.36, 10.9, 11.15, 
                                                                                                             10.1, 4.25, 4.24, 28.98, 20.99, 19.89), no_attend_lowCI = c(9.65, 
                                                                                                                                                                         6.5, 6.14, 2.74, 6.76, 6.39, 28.51, 19.58, 19.43), attend_lowCI = c(13.86, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             9.4, 9.65, 8.6, 2.75, 2.74, 27.48, 19.49, 18.39), no_attend_upperCI = c(12.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     9.05, 8.69, 5.29, 9.31, 8.94, 31.06, 22.13, 21.98), attend_upperCI = c(16.41, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            11.95, 12.2, 11.15, 5.3, 5.29, 30.03, 22.04, 20.94)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
dtest %>%
  pivot_longer(-var,
               names_pattern = "(.*attend)_(.*)",
               names_to = c("attend", "metric")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("var", "attend"),
              names_from = "metric")
#> # A tibble: 18 × 5
#>    var       attend     mean lowCI upperCI
#>    <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 jbj_ext_1 no_attend 11.2   9.65   12.2 
#>  2 jbj_ext_1 attend    15.4  13.9    16.4 
#>  3 jbj_ext_2 no_attend  8     6.5     9.05
#>  4 jbj_ext_2 attend    10.9   9.4    12.0 
#>  5 jbj_ext_3 no_attend  7.64  6.14    8.69
#>  6 jbj_ext_3 attend    11.2   9.65   12.2 
#>  7 jbj_int_1 no_attend  4.24  2.74    5.29
#>  8 jbj_int_1 attend    10.1   8.6    11.2 
#>  9 jbj_int_2 no_attend  8.26  6.76    9.31
#> 10 jbj_int_2 attend     4.25  2.75    5.3 
#> 11 jbj_int_3 no_attend  7.89  6.39    8.94
#> 12 jbj_int_3 attend     4.24  2.74    5.29
#> 13 jbj_tot_1 no_attend 30.0  28.5    31.1 
#> 14 jbj_tot_1 attend    29.0  27.5    30.0 
#> 15 jbj_tot_2 no_attend 21.1  19.6    22.1 
#> 16 jbj_tot_2 attend    21.0  19.5    22.0 
#> 17 jbj_tot_3 no_attend 20.9  19.4    22.0 
#> 18 jbj_tot_3 attend    19.9  18.4    20.9
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>